# Access to an Android phone from an Android tablet

Tags: android, usb, host

I have seen many questions about the usb, the host, the permissions, ... I never read a solution.

I have an Android/Windows tablet with a 'big' USB A port. I prefer to use the tablet with Android OS for many reasons. I can connect an Android phone with a standard USB cable. When the connection is made, the application Gallery is automatically running on the tablet and I can see the camera files stored on the phone. And I can only import them with this app.

This is a good feature but I would like to create a small app to copy the files instead of using Gallery. With java, I can have access to paths like **dev/bus/usb/xxx** but nothing else.
When I use es explorer, I can see the same paths but they are **not shown as folders**. They are shown as files and, if I select one of them, I get a choice between "open as text file", ...

So, how to have access to the real folders of the phone?
The app Gallery is able to do it. I think we should do the same even if the tablet is not rooted.

If I cannot do it, the only solution for me is using the Windows OS installed on the tablet. It seems it's easier to have access to a device than using Android. That's a bit strange, isn't it? But I prefer to use Android because the system is more appropriate for the tablet which has a small RAM.

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/quandoo/android2android-accessory but like a file transfer where the app only needs to manage selecting a file to transfer?

Comment: I tried to use the 'accessory' but it seems that only manages accessories like a mouse, ...